# Allow manual price override after price rule execution

Tags: cpq, pricerule

We have a generic price rule configured, which sets the list price based on the attribute values selected. We have a formula field which is the concatenation of all the different attribute fields and then use that as a key to get the price which is stored in a different object. But we also want the user to be able to manually override the price set by the rule. Currently I am unable to figure out how to achieve this as the price rule is executed again after manual price change. Any info is helpful.

This is how the rule is currently configured

[image]

Price Action config:

[image]